# Cloud Firestore big data error - Deadline Exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to download the data in Firestore as json and use it with realtime-database. For this, I found a project where I can download the data in the firestore in github in json format.

**Github Project:**
https://github.com/dalenguyen/firestore-import-export

This project is running but when I want to download large amounts of data I get the following error. The data I want to download is about 4 million. I upgraded the Firebase account to the paid plan and I did not understand the reason for this problem. I would be glad if you can help with this.

> The error I got:

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:91:15)
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:233:26)
    at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:211:8)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1277:15)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at C:\Users\ixast\Downloads\firestore-import-export-master\firestore-import-export-master\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1033:24 {
  code: 4,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {}, flags: 0 },
  details: 'Deadline Exceeded'
}
```

> Script:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const fs = require('fs');
const serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");

let collectionName = process.argv[2];
let subCollection = process.argv[3];

// You should replace databaseURL with your own
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
});

let db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

let data = {};
data[collectionName] = {};
var counter = 0

let results = db.collection(collectionName)
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    data[collectionName][doc.id] = doc.data();
    counter++;

  })
  return data;
  console.log(counter);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})

results.then(dt => {  
  getSubCollection(dt).then(() => {    
    // Write collection to JSON file
    fs.writeFile("firestore-export.json", JSON.stringify(data), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
  })  
})

async function getSubCollection(dt){
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries([dt[collectionName]][0])){
    if(subCollection !== undefined){
      data[collectionName][key]['subCollection'] = {};
      await addSubCollection(key, data[collectionName][key]['subCollection']);            
    }          
  }  
}

function addSubCollection(key, subData){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    db.collection(collectionName).doc(key).collection(subCollection).get()
    .then(snapshot => {      
      snapshot.forEach(subDoc => {             
        subData[subDoc.id] =  subDoc.data();
        resolve('Added data');                                                                 
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Split up your query using pagination rather than trying to do everything at once.

Comment: can you say me, how can i split it? i used startAt() and limit() but doesnt work

Comment: The pagination API works just fine.  If you're having a problem with it, please post a new question with the code that isn't working the way you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: i fixed it dear thank you